# Excel Formula for a cell

Tags: microsoft-excel

I need a formula in excel, to copy and display a value from cell A1 to B1, if cell A1 value is changed from a positive value to zero, the value in cell B1 must not change, it must retain its previous value(which is always greater than zero).
The value are numbers.

Comment: You cannot achieve it with mere formulas, and would be required to use VBA to do so! Are you open to using macros in the spreadsheet? Also, what are the approaches you have tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This cannot be done with formula's alone. But with the following VBA code, that is based on the [SelectionChange event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194470(v=office.15).aspx), it works:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
    Const SourceCell = "$A$1"
    Const TargetCell = "$A$2"

    If Target.Address = SourceCell Then
        If Range(SourceCell).Value > 0 Then
            Range(TargetCell).Value = Range(SourceCell).Value
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Or, if you want to have more source and target cell's (as requested later):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
    Dim SourceCells(), TargetCells() As Variant
    Dim i As Integer

    ' Make sure the cells are declared with $'s
    ' Make sure that the arrays contain the same number of elements
    SourceCells = Array("$B$1", "$B$2", "$F$5")
    TargetCells = Array("$A$1", "$A$2", "$H$12")

    For i = 0 To UBound(SourceCells)
        If Target.Address = SourceCells(i) Then
            If Range(SourceCells(i)).Value > 0 Then
                Range(TargetCells(i)).Value = Range(SourceCells(i)).Value
            End If
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

Put this code inside the VBA Code of the **worksheet** where you want this to be done. To do this, follow these instructions:

- In Excel, with your Workbook open, click `ALT`+`F11`. This opens the VBA editor.
- Check the "Project"-tree on the left, en find your Excel workbook and the worksheet. Right click (with your mouse) on that worksheet and select `View Code`.
- Copy-paste the code above into the editor.
- Close the VBA editor and everything should work as expected.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer, it works. but can you make the cell A1 refresh so it take the latest value on cell B1.

Comment: Change the SourceCell to "$B$1" and the TargetCell to "$A$1".

Comment: How can i add more source and target cell.

Comment: Added a second code example which does just that.

Comment: I have tried the vba code, but the problem is that all the cell are getting the same value. i need B1 value in A1 and B2 value in A2.

Comment: This is a good clean answer.